Issue with p6spy Logging in Spring Boot Application
I’m using p6spy-spring-boot-starter in my Spring Boot application to analyze MySQL queries. I’ve added the following dependencies in my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.gavlyukovskiy</groupId>
    <artifactId>p6spy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.26</version>
</dependency>

In my application.properties, I’ve included the following property because I don’t want to generate any logs; instead, I want to set up monitoring based on captured metrics.
decorator.datasource.p6spy.enable-logging=false

Additionally, I’ve created a custom JDBC event listener to capture metrics:
public class CustomJdbcEventListener extends SimpleJdbcEventListener {

  private final MetricManager metricManager;

  public CustomJdbcEventListener(MetricManager metricManager) {
    this.metricManager = metricManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAfterAnyExecute(StatementInformation statementInformation,
                                long timeElapsedNanos,
                                SQLException e) {
    long timeElapsedMs = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(timeElapsedNanos);
    String metricName = "SQL_STATEMENT " + statementInformation.getStatementQuery();
    metricManager.registerCustomMetric(metricName);
    metricManager.setCustomMetricsValue(metricName, timeElapsedMs);
  }
}

I’m injecting this listener using the following configuration:
@Configuration
public class CustomJdbcListenerConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CustomJdbcEventListener getCustomJdbcEventListener(MetricManager metricManager) {
    return new CustomJdbcEventListener(metricManager);
  }
}

However, when I start the application, I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't create PrintStream for spy.log (Permission Denied)

Despite setting decorator.datasource.p6spy.enable-logging=false, the application seems to be trying to create a spy.log file, which I don't want.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
